# JavaScript Removing anything after char in 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, char

if I have data

```
    dogNames = [[]];

    dogNames.push([Bill],[Ben],[jack, Allen],[Barbra],[Jill, Jenny],[George]);
```

if i wanted to loop though and print all to console e.g.

```
  for(let x=0;x<dogNames.length;x++){
       console.log(dogNames[x]);
    }
```

is it possible to hide any value after ',' in each array

so my printed value may be

Bill
Ben
Jack
Barbra
Jill
George

with Allen and Jenny both hidden/removed

Unsure where to start. tried using .split() but unsure how to use it on 2d arrays.

Comment: your dogNames are 2 dimensional array and you are printing one dimension. Inside your for loop, there should be another for loop to print individual item. additionally, you are accessing as `dogNames(x)`, I wonder if you have a function name dogNames

Comment: `dogNames.push([Bill],[Ben],[jack, Allen],[Barbra],[Jill, Jenny],[George]);` doesn't really exist, and then it matters a lot that if your actual code has `...["jack, Allen"]...` or `...["jack", "Allen"]...` in it.

Answer (score 1):

You have several syntax mistakes like parens around x which should be square brackets and also you need strings to be in quotes in the arrays.

Also you don't need an array in an array when you first declare *dogNames*

If you compare your code with my code you will see what I mean.

The main answer to your question is to include the `[0]` in `console.log(dogNames[x][0]);` so you just log the first element of the sub arrays

```js
dogNames = [];

dogNames.push(['Bill'],['Ben'],['jack', 'Allen'],['Barbra'],['Jill', 'Jenny'],['George']);
  
for(let x=0;x<dogNames.length;x++){
  console.log(dogNames[x][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.split(",") is for strings, you are using arrays.
So basically you can convert to string and split or just pick the first element of every row (your second array).

```
dogNames = [[]];
dogNames.push(["Bill"],["Ben"],["jack", "Allen"],["Barbra"],["Jill", "Jenny"],["George"]);


// SOLUTION 1 --> JUST PICK ARRAY FIRST ELEMENT
for(let x=0;x<dogNames.length; x++){
  console.log(dogNames[x][0]);
}

//SOLUTION 2 --> ARRAY to STRING
for(let x=0;x<dogNames.length;x++){
 const dogNameRow = dogNames[x];
 const dogString = dogNameRow.join();
 console.log(dogString.split(",")[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this requirement with the help of [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const dogNames = [[],['Bill'],['Ben'],['jack', 'Allen'],['Barbra'],['Jill', 'Jenny'],['George']];

console.log(dogNames.map(arr => arr[0]).filter(Boolean).join())
```